# How to do a Prototype validation

Tags: react-native

My Eslint ( Airbnb ), tells me I need to do a prototype validation, Googled it and couldn't find out how to do it in react-native. Help ? 
Thank you

Comment: You've probably mistaken `propType` with `prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this this would do
If you're only using ES6 classes the correct way to define propTypes is shown in the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html):

```
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Counter.propTypes = { initialCount: React.PropTypes.number };
Counter.defaultProps = { initialCount: 0 }
```